# Input data for compression algorithm

Tags: image-processing, compression, image-compression

I want to implement the algorithm from the paper [DhyaaAlrahman Latef Thajel1, Kadhim Mahdi Hashim1 - A New Technique for Data Compression](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/928/3/032002/pdf). However in section 3.1.1, it says that it needs a binary image as input.

My question is, does it mean that the method only applies to binary data (black and white)? Or that it applies to any image (as RGB) but that it needs to be converted before? if yes, how?

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but this may refer to 1bpp images. Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format and look for  "1-bit per pixel (1bpp) format".

Comment: @MBaz thanks for the comment. Yes, that it what I thought... But in this case the algorithm doesnt seem very useful I think.. That is why I found it strange

Comment: Well, many algorithms take binary data as input, but then they group bits into words of specific size. Having data in a different format could obscure the performance of the compressor. As an extreme example, image data stored as IEEE floating point would result in most pixels having a common mantissa.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I understand. If I use this algorithm in a common rgb color then I would lose not only the color information but all possible variations of colors between 0 and 255 (since i ll have only 0 and 1). No?

Comment: Or maybe I am understanding things wrong and treating a, lets say, grayscale image as binary in this case means splitting every pixel that would go from 0 to 255 in 8 binary pixels?

Comment: It seems that the authors are using a binary image just for testing. You can still read an RGB image bit by bit and use this same algorithm.

Comment: After 5 minutes reading the full paper, I'm not so sure. It may be that the algorithm only works with binary images... The beauty of peer-review! The best course here may be to contact the authors and ask them directly.

Comment: I see. I think I would rather pick another algorithm then. Do you know any other algorithm for data compression that would be interesting to implement?

Comment: I cannot make heads or tails of that paper. If a paper on image compression is published in a conference on Materials Science and Engineering, it is a good bet the conference nor any of the papers presented in it are worth your time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo good point.

Comment: @Manveru That may be worth asking a new question on. Why do you want to do this? Time frame? Classic or state-of-the-art? Etc.

Comment: @MBaz I asked once but my question was closed.. I dont know why. Its a semester project of a course of data compression at university. Professor asked us to propose topics so I started to look after papers on data compression to implement and found this one. The thing is that I have no knowledge of which algorithms are doable without previous knowledge and in a reasonable amount of time. There is no need for SOTA results, just to show some practical work in the area.

Comment: https://phoboslab.org/log/2021/11/qoi-fast-lossless-image-compression ?

Comment: Thanks! I ll study that

Comment: recommendation: @Manveru find a more classic paper! Start with what is in the references of the appropriate wikipedia articles. That paper you found is of really low quality.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks. Indeed I am having a look on the family of algorithms LZW as well. It seems easy enough for me to understand

Comment: excellent choice. LZW, LZ77 and other variants have very high practical relevance!